# HTML loading first before loading all the page

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I have a major issue with my page load method, whenever my page start loading I can see HTML before loading of the page in proper manner.

There I am using cache for HTML, CSS and JS to serve on page for speed, the speed is fast now, but really its looking weird when we can see broken HTML at the time of page load.

I have tried multiple things:

```
1. Tried unminified CSS
2. Tried JS to show a blank page before full page load
3. Tried uncached CSS
4. Tried to show percentage on page load
```

But not got success, the issue appears only for miliseconds before page load then start showing percentage or whatever I am trying, but before all of the solutions once it is showing the bad mannered HTML.

Please give me suggestions, why it is appearing with valuable reasons and what exact reason behind this.
[Click here to view problem when site loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62XL5.png)

Comment: what type of code Do you need page URL?

Comment: Yup, a link would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing your unstyled HTML load first is simply because your stylesheets are not getting loaded first. You need to place your external stylesheets in the head section of your HTML so that it gets loaded first.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
<!-- Load your style sheets here -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All my styles are in <head></head> section.

Comment: From what I can see from your site URL, you are loading your css via javascript asynchronously. Not the way I wrote it above.

Comment: Can you please drop me code from view page source that whats wrong there, that will be very helpful.

Comment: From what I can see from your souce code, you are using wordpress. So you are probably using a plugin with an option enabled to load your css via javascript.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the code: http://snpy.in/FadtxV .You can all `.css`file is being loaded via javascript.

Comment: Which plugin are you using in WP to speed up/optimize your site? You are probably using the wrong settings that's why it is loaded via JS.

Comment: means I have to remove css load thorugh JS? Is this solve my issue?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. By default, this is not a feature in WordPress. You have probably done this through a plugin like WP rocket or PageSpeed Module.

Comment: Yes you are right I am using WP rocket, so why they given this feature? And there is no any settings like that.